# Can I overlap exactly half of an image with another using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to overlap exactly half an image in CSS using another image. Thing is I want the height of the images to be say (x=200px). The width of the image will wary depending on the aspect ratio of the image. Can I still write CSS that will overlap exactly half of the resized image with another image.

Following is a code where I have played around with the position of the overlapping image. Can I let CSS do this for me somehow? Or is there some js that can help? In the following code I want the height to be unchanged, but half of any image used should be overlapped widthwise.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            #collage-container{
                width:300px;
                height: 200px;
                position: relative;
                background:#f22;
            }

            #collage-one, #collage-two{
                height:200px;
                position:absolute;
            }

            #collage-one{
                z-index:1;
                left:100px;
                position:absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=collage-container>
            <img src="http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp" id=collage-one />
            <img src="http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp" id=collage-two />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would `margin-left:50%;` on your second image work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `width` of images is vary, you could use [CSS transform `translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) expression with a [percentage value](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-property) to move images to a side with the respect to their `width` value:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/yegeh/2/edit)**

```css
#collage-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#collage-container img {
  height: 100%; /* As tall as the container */
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

#collage-container img + img {  /* Move the second image 50% of its width */
  transform: translateX(-50%);  /*  to the left */
}
```

It's worth noting that CSS transforms are supported in **[IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)**

Comment: Don't forget to include `-webkit`, `-moz`, `-ms`, `-o` prefixes. [Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/yegeh/25/edit).

Comment: Can we write something that will be supported in older IE versions as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
  .container {
    float:left;
  }
  .half-img {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
  } 
  .clear {clear:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <span class="half-img">
    <img src="http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp" width="100">
  </span><img src="http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp" width="100">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```